# Conditional insert with table locking POSTGRES SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking

I am trying to accomplish this logic in a postgreSQL table:

1. Check if a row of certain conditions exists.
2. If it exists, do nothing.
3. If it does not exist, insert a new row with certain values.
4. Return the row that was inserted, or nothing if nothing was inserted.
5. Do so in a way that if two processes try to do this at the same time, the 2nd one will be blocked out of **viewing** the table until the first one completes the conditional insert.

My current query looks like this: (Passing in `id`, `bike_id`, `status` and `status_to_conflict_on`).

`ride_id` is the primary key.

```
BEGIN;
LOCK TABLE rides in ACCESS EXCLUSIVE MODE;
INSERT INTO rides (ride_id, bike_id,  status, inserted_dt, updated_dt)
SELECT :ride_id, :bike_id, status::status, now(), now()
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM rides WHERE bike_id=:bike_id AND status::text IN (<statuses_to_conflict_on>)
);
COMMIT;
SELECT * FROM rides WHERE ride_id=:ride_id;
```

Currently I am getting this error:
`SQL command failed to the database org.jdbi.v3.core.result.NoResultsException: Statement returned no results`, If anyone knows if my syntax is wrong, or there is a better way to accomplish what I have described it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I don't know if this will work, but try getting rid of the `select` after the `commit`, and add `returning *` to the end of the `insert`.

Comment: @MikeOrganek Ah yeah, I tried that before, I don't think it works because the `commit` only returns that the commit happened or didn't happen, no values from inside.

Comment: Have you tried eliminating the `begin` and `commit` from your code block and making `jdbi` run the bare block as a transaction with `inTransaction()`?

Comment: @MikeOrganek Trying, getting an error `Not enough information to infer type variable X`
code:
 ```return withHandleSingle(activeSpanContext()) { handle ->
            handle.inTransaction { h ->
                h.createQuery(QUERY_INSERT_RIDE_PLACEHOLDER_TEST)
                    .bind("ride_id", UUID.randomUUID())
                    .bind("bike_id", bike_id)
                    .bind("status", status)
                    .bindList("statuses_to_conflict_on", statusesToConflictOn)
                    .map(::mapDbRide)
                    .list()
            }}``` 

(In Kotlin BTW)

Comment: It worked with `begin` and `commit` but doesn't work without them?  I'm sorry I cannot help.  I quit ORMs for good almost twenty years ago.

Comment: If you want to prevent duplicates, then why not simply create a unique index? That will be a lot easier to work with and also way more efficient

Comment: @MikeOrganek The error was with the syntax of `inTransaction()`, hadn't even gotten to running the SQL yet ah!

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name The requirement for this is that two concurrent processes need to check if a row exists, but then insert if it doesn't, but they will end up inserting with different primary keys (two rows inserted). I need to lock the DB **before** the SELECT statement that determines if the process should insert or not.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ooooh, maybe that would be a great idea though, I'm not too familiar with indexes!

Comment: You can have unique indexes (or constraint) other than the primary key